# ThreadLocal DecimalFormat does not format properly

Tags: java, decimalformat, thread-local

I have a ThreadLocal object below:

```
  private static final ThreadLocal< DecimalFormat > formatter = new ThreadLocal< DecimalFormat >() 
  {
    @Override
    protected DecimalFormat initialValue() 
    {
    // n should be any number of decimals without having to specify them.
      return new DecimalFormat();     
    }
  };
```

When I run `formatter.get.format(1234567)` in a German Locale I get: `123456,0` which is not what I want.

I changed the ThreadLocal object to:

```
  private static final ThreadLocal< DecimalFormat > localisedDecimalFormatter = new ThreadLocal< DecimalFormat >() 
  {
    public DecimalFormat get() 
    {
      return new DecimalFormat();
    }    
  };
```

When I run `formatter.get.format(1234567)` in a German Locale I get: `123.456` which is exactly what I want.

Using DecimalFormat format(123456) gives the expected value, but isn't thread safe

My question is, is this an improper use of ThreadLocal? If so, how could I use it without making use of bad coding practices? (I'm aware I could use formatter.remove() to trigger initialValue() everytime but not sure if it's an overkill)

Comment: Creating a new formatter each time and use that for formatting should be perfectly thread safe. Just dont share the formatter instance?!

Comment: @NathanHughes By 'create a new one' do you mean a new DecimalFormat?

Comment: yes. the point of having a threadlocal is so each thread gets its own copy (of the DecimalFormat object) that is preserved from one call to the next. (A ThreadLocal is like a threadsafe map where each thread can store its own copy of something) otherwise just instantiate a new one whenever you need it.

Comment: @NathanHughes fair point.If there is a way to remove a Pattern without reinstantiating the DecimalFormat, then the original implementation would work fine. After looking into it I was not able to find such a way.